# How could be Laravel Socialite be integrated with a SPA?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, nuxt.js

I know we have the stateless() and and getTargetUrl() methods, than i am trying this at my controller:

```
public function socialRedirect($provider){

        return Socialite::with($provider)->stateless()->redirect()->getTargetUrl();
    }
```

The problem is that in my SPA front end, i can't make a sucessfull request to the provided url as like in the code below:

```
async facebookLogin() {
      try {
      const url = await this.$axios.$get('/auth/social/facebook')
      this.$axios.$get(url)
      } catch (error){
        console.log(error)
      }
    },
```

I get CORS related stuff errors:

```
OPTIONShttps://www.facebook.com/v3.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=240805606930310&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8000/api/auth/social/facebook/callback&scope=email&response_type=code
CORS Missing Allow Origin
```

What am i doing wrong? I am specially confused since i can access the URL by copying it and pasting in another browser tab, but i can't sucessfully make the AJAX request to it.

Comment: check if your facebook settings for the oauth consumer client you made has added localhost in the list of allowed origins

Comment: you mean permitted domains for SDK JS client  at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/240805606930310/fb-login/settings/ section?

Comment: yes that sounds about right

Comment: i listed the domain there but nothing changed. Anyway, i am not using any facebook SDK at the frontend. Laravel API is the one responsible for making the authentication requests.

Comment: Try when you list it to list it as `http://localhost:8000` (port included) in case that works

Comment: Tried it but no success :{